# sklearn запрос по api mutual_info_regression

Tags: python, sklearn

Хочу получить взаимную информацию каждых 2х признаков через метод ближайшего соседа. В `mutual_info_regression` предустановлено 3 признака для расчетов. работающий код:

```
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k='all').fit(X, y)
```

Как сделать для 2х признаков?
Приведенные ниже варианты вызывают ошибки:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest,mutual_info_regression
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k='all').fit(X, y,**{'n_neighbors':2})
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression(**{'n_neighbors':2}), k='all').fit(X, y)
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression(n_neighbors=2), k='all').fit(X, y)
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression,n_neighbors=2, k='all').fit(X, y)
```

При попытке зайти через make_scorer:

```
scoring = make_scorer(mutual_info_regression, greater_is_better=True, n_neighbors = 2)

selector = SelectKBest(scoring, k='all').fit(feat, targ)
```

ошибка:

> TypeError: **call**() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Что за ошибки хотя бы?

Comment: По идее надо через `make_scorer` делать, но у меня не получилось всё-равно. Надо ещё думать.

Comment: @CrazyElf попробовала через make_scorer. ошибка 3 аргумента, вместо 4х

Comment: Да я знаю, поэтому и написал, что не получилось, хотя заходить нужно откуда-то оттуда. Надо думать, что с аргументами и что вообще происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение, через partial. Можно заменить существующую функцию, которой уже переданы аргументы переопределение функции:

```
from functools import partial
scorer_function = partial(mutual_info_regression, n_neighbors=2)
selector = SelectKBest(scorer_function, k='all').fit(X, y)
```